# Visual Studio update 3 installer is trying to install update 2 instead

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

.NET Core 1.0.0 was released yesterday and it needs VS update 3 to be installed.

So I downloaded the installer from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs-knownissues/vs2015-update3) and tried installing but this weird issue is happening:

[image: pic]

It's as if the installer is trying to get update 2 instead of update 3. I'm already on update 2 and it's telling me that. I tried searching but didn't find anything on the subject. Also tried restarting my machine.

And now I'm being blocked by this since I already uninstalled .NET Core RC2, and .NET Core 1.0.0 doesn't want to install before VS update 3.

Comment: What does the little (i) say when you hover your mouse over it? Also, why don't you just try installing it and see what happens... maybe it will install update 3 after all

Comment: @phil13131 can't install anything. The (i) tells me that update 2 is already fully installed. The "UPDATE" button is grayed out as you can see.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Forget the downloaded update, just go to Programs and Features, double click Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and choose "Modify" from the VS installer options. Update 3 will be available there.

Comment: This does not work for me. I have "Visual Studio 2015 with Update 2" installed. So there is no Update 2 to double click. Also, double clicking the VS itself does not bring any option to install the update 3.

Comment: Maybe your install is fubar after all the beta/RC stuff they have put out. Just reinstall would be my advice in this situation, and only install the RTM bits. Don't forget to also install the NET Core tooling after the fresh VS2015 install (from MS site)

Comment: What I had to do was to download the full "Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (x86 and x64) - DVD (Multiple Languages)" , not the web install version .

Comment: This did work for me, with Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

Answer (score 6):

Check this -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/vs-knownissues/vs2015-update3

"Workaround:

Instead of installing Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 by using VS2015.3.exe, install the update by using a full product installer. You can find installers for "Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3" on the [Visual Studio download page](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs). Select the "Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3" download that matches the edition you already have installed, whether Community, Professional, or Enterprise.

Alternatively, you can follow the steps in [Updating an installation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee225237.aspx#Anchor_4) to force an update to the layouts."

Answer (score 4):

I faced this problem 
I solved it by downloading the offline iso file then installed it from the iso file

you can find offline iso file
http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2016/06/visual-studio-2015-update-3.html

the direct links
 Visual Studio Community 2015 with Update 3 - iso

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615448&clcid=0x409
Visual Studio 2015 Update 3  -  ISO
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=708984

Comment: This solution worked for me on my dev machine.  However, the accepted solution worked on our build server.  Go figure.  Not sure what the difference was...

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to not use the download. Instead, open **Program and Features** from the Control Panel. Select "Visual Studio 2015 with Updates" (or your equivalent), and click Change. From the installation dialog, click Modify and you should see Update 3 available to be selected.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Following your suggestion, I get to the installation dialog, but I only get "Repair" or "Uninstall" options on that dialog.  No "Modify" option...

Comment: I wonder if it's related to which edition of Visual Studio is installed. In my case, it's Enterprise edition.

Comment: I am using VS2015 Community and indeed there is a "Modify" option - you have to select "Program and Features" (Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features) and then find VS2015 Update to otherwise you'll just get the "Repair" or "Unistall".

Comment: I'm using Enterprise, and there's no Modify under the Update 2 option.

For info, I ended up installing using the full ISO (7GB, wowzers, that took a while to download, and then some of the packages in it were corrupt and had to re-downloaded!).  Doing it like that worked.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the full installer Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 - ISO I ran it from admin command prompt with vs2015.3.exe /Passive

With the /Passive switch it finally installed the upate!